# Check whether environment variable is empty

Tags: github-actions

What is the nicest approach to check if environment variable is empty on Github action as a condition to a step? I've tried the trivial approach but it doesn't seem to work.

For example:

```yaml
name: SimpleWorkflow

on:
  push:   

env:
  MULTI_LINE_ARG: |
  ARG1: value
jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fetching Local Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: run step if multiline not null
        if: ${{env.MULTI_LINE_ARG}} != ""
        run: echo multiline not null
```

No matter how I've tried this I fail to properly check if env is empty.

Comment: Did you try doing it directly in a `run` step? (Example: https://github.community/t/if-expression-with-context-variable/16558/2). It's quite verbose, but it would be a valid workaround.

Answer (score 15):

### Checking for environment variables

In case one added an environment variable as described at [Creating configuration variables for an environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-an-environment), one can use `if: ${{ env:VAR_NAME == '' }}` for checking.

The following example provides an example workflow for the environment variable `TEXT`.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
env:
  env_text: ${{ vars.TEXT }}
jobs:
  greeting_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - if: ${{ env.env_text == '' }}
        run: |
          echo "Empty text"
      - if: ${{ env.env_text != '' }}
        run: |
          echo "Text: '$env_text'"
```

In case the variable is not defined, the output is as follows:

[image: result-for-unset-variable]

In case the variable is defined, the output is as follows:

[image: result-for-set-variable]

### Checking for secrets

Background: The issue of secrets not available to forks is known to GitHub folks, but no concrete activity announced: https://github.community/t/github-workflow-not-running-from-pull-request-from-forked-repository/16379/41?u=koppor

One can use output variables of steps to determine whether a secret is available.

The name of the secret in GitHub is `SECRET`.

```yaml
      - name: Check secrets presence
        id: checksecrets
        shell: bash
        run: |
          if [ "$SECRET" == "" ]; then
            echo "secretspresent=NO" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "secretspresent=YES" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
        env:
          SECRET: ${{ secrets.SECRET}}
      - name: run step if secret is present
        if: (steps.checksecrets.outputs.secretspresent == 'YES')
        run: echo secret is present
```

Note: Solution adapted from https://github.community/t/if-expression-with-context-variable/16558/6?u=koppor.

Comment: What does this have to do with checking if an environment variable is empty as part of a conditional statement on a step?

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you for the hint, I updated the answer accordingly